# arraylist set(int x,string item) then what is the size?

Tags: arraylist, set

If i add an item in an arraylist with the set method,for example:

myArrayList.set(10, myItem);

then the size of the arraylist becomes 10?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quoting the Oracle Documentation file:

> set(int index, E element)
>
> ```
> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element.
> ```

next time, Google it first:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: next time, don't answer first.

Answer (score 0):

If you set an index of an ArrayList, the value is merely replaced, and thus the size of the ArrayList remains the same. If you were to use the `add` method, however, the size would increase by one.